# How to support multiple source level targets in an annotation processor

Tags: java

My team and I are maintaining some applications that contain code generated using  the [Maven annotation plugin](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin).

I was testing a migration from Java 8 to Java 11 when I realized that the generated code does not compile, no matter how I configured the plugin, Maven or Eclipse. Once JDK 11 was installed, an error was reported by the compiler about not being able to locate `javax.annotation.Generated` for import.

I've just discovered that that specific import is actually inserted by our own annotation processor.

I can't just change the package of `Generated` from `javax.annotation.Generated` (in Java 8) to `javax.annotation.processing.Generated` (in Java 11) since there will be some time (possibly up to a year) when we'll be using both platforms. I am now wondering whether and how I could dynamically select which annotation package to import in the generated files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to solve a different problem than the one I've described in this question, I came across an answer that I'm sharing here. It comes from class `Context` in org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.4.4.Final

```
        TypeElement java8AndBelowGeneratedAnnotation =
                pe.getElementUtils().getTypeElement( "javax.annotation.Generated" );
        if ( java8AndBelowGeneratedAnnotation != null ) {
            generatedAnnotation = java8AndBelowGeneratedAnnotation;
        }
        else {
            // Using the new name for this annotation in Java 9 and above
            generatedAnnotation = pe.getElementUtils().getTypeElement( "javax.annotation.processing.Generated" );
        }
```

The nugget of knowledge here is that by trying to access the "old" annotation, one can determine which platform is running.

**Beware!** Note however that `javax.annotation.Generated` might be brought in by a third-party library (and not by the JRE), **which will invalidate this dynamic selection of the appropriate annotation**. This is happening to me at this very moment due to javax.annotation:jsr250-api being indirectly brought by org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin into the build environment of my project. As a result, the Hibernate annotation processor wrongly outputs `javax.annotation.Generated` instead of outputting `javax.annotation.processing.Generated` as it should in a Java 11 environment.